# speech to text flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, speech-recognition

I am trying to use the package speech to text in flutter , I am using a Pixel 6 Pro with android 11, I followed every instruction and set up my build.gradle file the following way :

```
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 33
```

I also added the following to manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

However when im trying to use the functionnality i get this error
E/SpeechToTextPlugin( 7739): Speech recognition not available on this device
E/flutter ( 7739): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(recognizerNotAvailable, Speech recognition not available on this device, , null)
E/flutter ( 7739): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653:7)
E/flutter ( 7739): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:296:18)
E/flutter ( 7739): 
E/flutter ( 7739): #2      MethodChannelSpeechToText.initialize (package:speech_to_text_platform_interface/method_channel_speech_to_text.dart:39:12)
E/flutter ( 7739): 
E/flutter ( 7739): #3      SpeechToText.initialize (package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart:288:19)
E/flutter ( 7739): 
E/flutter ( 7739): #4      _speech_recoState._listen (package:nut/Pages/speech_reco.dart:105:24)
E/flutter ( 7739): 
E/flutter ( 7739):

can someone please help !

I want to convert speech to text

Answer (score -1):

**It seems that the error is saying that "Speech recognition is not available on this device". This could be due to several reasons:
The device doesn't have a built-in speech recognition system or doesn't support the speech recognition API you're using.
The required permissions are not granted in your app. Make sure you have added the required permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml file as mentioned in your code snippet.
The speech recognition service you are using is not installed or not configured correctly.
You can try checking if your device has a built-in speech recognition system by searching for the feature in the device settings or by checking the device specifications. If your device doesn't have the feature, you could try using a different speech recognition service or API.**